# How do I pivot a table while keeping the other columns intact

Tags: python, pandas

I have looked around and I have not been able to exactly get the result I am looking for.

I have the following Dataframe:

[image]

My goal, is to have a dataframe that for every year-state combination, has columns white, black, hispanic, asian, with values in Score. I would expect the dataframe to get a lot shorter.

I have tried to do the following:

(raceexpanded is the df provided)

`racedf = raceexpanded.pivot(values='Score', index=['Year','State'], columns='Race')`

but I get the error ValueError: Length of passed values is 1908, index implies 2